# Trying to find the latest date prior to a specific date for a specific location

Tags: excel, max, lookup

I have looked thru multiple forums but have not found what I am trying to do. Any help is appreciated.

I have a table with locations in the first column and truck delivery dates per location off to the right.

What I am trying to do is look for the latest delivery date prior to a specific date for a specific location. MAX formula works great to find the date but I have a trouble finding based on location number lookup.

In the example below, I'm looking for the latest date prior to 7/20/2020 for location 110. Correct date is 7/8/2020.

[image: Truck arrival date by location]

MAX formula I can specify row 3 but I need to be able to look up multiple location and have not found a way lookup.

Comment: Don't you think it's gonna be hard to help you when you don't even mention the software you are using?

Comment: Do you use some SQL query?

Comment: Sorry, I'm supplied with an Excel sheet with the shipping dates and the look up information is also in Excel.

Comment: Solution found. Changing to Solved.